# What file format do I need to export as

Tags: export, import

I use Fusion360 to model and I would like to use Blender to render them. I just spent way too long trying to unwrap an imported STL file to apply a texture I just bought. Apparently it's impossible to ALT+click loops for a manual unwrap.

So my question is, what file format do I need to export as, in Fusion360, to be able to attach materials in Blender?[image]

Comment: If that's all of your options I'd use obj (human readable, not proprietary) but don't expect the geometry is the same (CAD vs. Mesh modeling). Export as separate objects, this way you can assign materials per object selection *or* split by loose parts in blender (*P*).

Answer (score 1):

In general, the format should not matter as each is supposed to bring the same data into Blender, as long as the format is supported. The unwrapping though does **not** depend on the format.

Not that format does not matter, but it really has no influence on the unwrapping, as that is based on the geometry that is generated from the data read in/generated inside Blender.
While i usually use fbx or obj, i believe the format can be chosen based on ease of handling with all eventually involved software and their support of it.

Update based on the video in the comment:

The situation of not being able to select loops will come up if the geometry does not offer Blender a continuous edge flow, thus only the edge or only the edges to a certain part will be selected. Most likely caused by either N-gons or Triangle-faces. In that case one would have to manually select with shortest path selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> or change the geometry to a more quad-based version with a clear flow of the edges.

I'd suggest to un-triangulate manually if the object is not too complex and thus allow an easier workflow from there.

In regards of the format, i had both fbx and obj files i imported with quads, so in your case, try to export the objects without triangulating them.

Comment: Yes I'm alt+left clicking.
Selecting loops works great for anything designed in Blender.

The alt+left clicks do not select loops for imported STLs or OBJ's.

btw what screen recorder software does everyone use? So I can record what is happening.

Comment: The software i use is called [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).
And i'm really wondering why Blender would treat imported obj files different.
I got some obj-files from the internet myself and had no issues working on them.

Comment: Ok here's a screen capture of what I'm doing. First I show that placing a cylinder, TABing into edit mode, ALT=left clicking, loop has been selected and can scale etc. Next I import an OBJ, TAB over into edit mode and show that ALT+left clicking does not work. 

https://youtu.be/nCSh9pE-Vkw

I don't mind sharing the file if needed, but none of my STL, OBJ or FBX files allow me to select loops. I can't be this retarded lol. I'm new to blender but I've done the icecream and donut tutorials many times.

Comment: After watching the video i know what the reason is that you can't select loops.
Your object does not have loops, as in continuous edges. All those triangle faces make the edges not go in a loop that Blender accepts. At least not with the default loop selection. Try triangulating a cylinder generated in Blender, just add one and then select all faces and press "Ctrl+T", You will have the same problem.
It's caused by the triangulation, sorry.

Comment: AND i have to admit that you can use "Alt+left" to loop select, thing is that using a pen, thus emulating the 3 button mouse and left click select makes the "Alt+left" loop selection unavailable, just to correct myself.